# Is the definite article needed in "the recommendation of (the) passenger"?

Tags: articles

I have a question about use of articles. Which of the below sentences are correct grammatically?

1. I saw a passenger in the street. **The recommendation of the passenger** was not to play football in the street!
2. I saw a passenger in the street. **The recommendation of passenger** was not to play football in the street!

Comment: The article is needed, but the whole thing doesn't make sense.

Comment: We can help you after you read how we work: Help/Tour.

Answer (score 6):

First, *passenger* means "somebody who travels in a vehicle but is not controlling that vehicle". It is incoherent to use "passenger" when there is no vehicle expressed or implied in the discourse. I suspect you mean "passer-by".

Secondly, a singular count noun such as "passenger" can hardly ever be used without an article, so your second sentence is ungrammatical as well as incoherent.